# Why basic_streambuf::pubseekoff() is not a pure virtual function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc, stream, streambuf

If you look at `<streambuf>`header file in VS2010 you'll see the definition of this member function as

```
pos_type pubseekoff(off_type _Off, ios_base::seekdir _Way,
                ios_base::openmode _Mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out)
{   // change position by _Off, according to _Way, _Mode
    return (seekoff(_Off, _Way, _Mode));
}
```

where `seekoff`is a virtual function, which is overridden in the derived classes `basic_filebuf` and `basic_stringbuf` and which does nothing in the base class `basic_streambuf` as can be seen below:

```
virtual pos_type seekoff(off_type, ios_base::seekdir,
                         ios_base::openmode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out)
{   // change position by offset, according to way and mode
    return (streampos(_BADOFF));
}
```

I couldn't find the definition of `_BADOFF`but it's probably `-1`. But that really doesn't matter here. This function, nor `pubseekoff`, will never be invoked, as the class `basic_streambuf`is an abstract class (its constructors are protected).

**Note also that the `gcc` compiler uses the same technique**. Why did the two compilers have to resort to the `seekoff()` member functions, instead of simply declaring `pubseekoff` as pure virtual in `basic_streambuf` and defining it in each one of the derived classes `basic_filebuf` and `basic_stringbuf`?

Comment: probably because the standard mandates it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same reason you don't normally make virtual functions
public.  Public functions define an interface, and the base
class needs to be able to capture them if it wants to enforce
that interface.  There are exceptions, when inversion of control
is involved, but in most cases, you simply don't make virtual
functions public.  How would you insert pre- and post-condition
checks if you did?  (See
http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm, for example.)

Comment: "... and the base class needs to be able to capture them if it wants to enforce that interface". I have no idea what you're talking about here.

Comment: @user1577873 The base class defines the contract for each function, including things like pre- and post-conditions.  In order to enforce the pre- and post-conditions, the base class must be able to insert code before and after the virtual function is called.  It must be able to "capture" the call, rather than have the call going through directly to the derived class.